# How to format the current date and time in SQL when creating a table but to only include the time by itself?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Im not sure how to format the 'default sysdate' to only have the time bit when ran?

so the output would be the current time '15:20:52' without the date.

I am using sql*plus

```
create table timeslot
(
tsdate default sysdate not null,
tstime default sysdate not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can convert to a string:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;
```

Comment: But you cant do it when you are creating the table initially?

Comment: @Hanikhattab . . . Oracle doesn't support a `time` data type.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not support any `time` data type. You can use `DATE` (i.e. `SYSDATE`) data type and just ignore the date part while using only the time part in your application.

Note, `DATE` datatype in Oracle always consist data and time value.